# Google Maps API V3 Marker Cluster with filterable markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There are lots of questions on Stackoverflow where people have kindly helped fix issues with MarkerClusterer, however, I am using a great little project from Twilliamson90 over on Github. Basically, it has allowed me to do some nice filtering of the markers and allowed me to link in some nice external data sets.

My issue now though is that I have too much data to easily display on the page without it looking too crowded. The obvioust solution is to add in marker clustering - unfortunately, I've not found it as easy as that.

I've been through several tutorials but I just can't make it work with the filtering.

I've pasted the javascript below, any help would be hugely appreciated. Hugely.

```
var TEST_MAP = 'custom_style';
var myMap = function() {

    var featureOpts = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#782B8B' },
        { visibility: 'simplified' },
        { gamma: 0.5 },
        { weight: 0.5 }
      ]
    },
    {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      stylers: [
        { color: '#782B8B' }
      ]
    }
  ];
    var options = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.967397, -2.043457),
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [TEST_MAP]
        },
        mapTypeId: TEST_MAP
    }

    /*
        Load the map then markers
        @param object settings (configuration options for map)
        @return undefined
    */
    function init(settings) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById( settings.idSelector ), options);

        var styledMapOptions = {
            name: 'Custom Style'
        };
        var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set(TEST_MAP, customMapType);

        markerLocation = settings.markerLocation;
        loadMarkers();
    }

    /*
        =======
        MARKERS
        =======
    */
    markers = {};
    markerList = [];

    /*
        Load markers onto the Google Map party a provided array or demo personData (data.js)
        @param array personList [optional] (list of people to load)
        @return undefined
    */
    function loadMarkers(personList) {

        // optional argument of person
        var people = ( typeof personList !== 'undefined' ) ? personList : personData;

        var j = 1; // for lorempixel

        for( i=0; i < people.length; i++ ) {
            var person = people[i];

            // if its already on the map, dont put it there again
            if( markerList.indexOf(person.id) !== -1 ) continue;

            var lat = person.lat,
                lng = person.lng,
                markerId = person.id;

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: 500
            });

            var iconImage = {
                url: person.markerIcon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(30, 40),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,40)
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
                title: person.name,
                markerId: markerId,
                icon: iconImage,
                map: map
            });

            markers[markerId] = marker;
            markerList.push(person.id);



var MarkerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(TEST_MAP, markers);

            var content = ['<div class="iw"><img src="', person.image, '">', '<div class="iw-text"><strong>', person.name, '</strong><br><strong>Applications:</strong> ', person.applications, '<br><strong>SIC Sub Class:</strong> ', person.sicSubClass, '<br><strong>Constituency:</strong> ', person.constituency, '<br><strong>Stream:</strong> ', person.stream, '<br><strong>Town:</strong> ', person.town, '<br><strong>Start date:</strong> ', person.startDate, '<br><strong>Offer grant:</strong> &pound;', person.grant, '<br><strong>Offer cost:</strong> &pound;', person.cost, '<br><strong>Payments to date:</strong> &pound;', person.payments, '<br><a target="blank_" href="', person.url, '">', person.url, '</a></div></div>'].join('');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(content);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, content));   

        }

    }



    /*
        Remove marker party map and our list of current markers
        @param int id (id of the marker element)
        @return undefined
    */
    function removePersonMarker(id) {
        if( markers[id] ) {
            markers[id].setMap(null);
            loc = markerList.indexOf(id);
            if (loc > -1) markerList.splice(loc, 1);
            delete markers[id];
        }
    }

    /*
        ======
        FILTER
        ======
    */

    // default all filters off
    var filter = {
        applications: 0,
        constituency: 0,
        town: 0,
        stream: 0,
        startDate: 0,
        party: 0
    }
    var filterMap;

    /*
        Helper function
        @param array a (array of arrays)
        @return array (common elements party all arrays)
    */
    function reduceArray(a) {
        r = a.shift().reduce(function(res, v) {
            if (res.indexOf(v) === -1 && a.every(function(a) {
                return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
            })) res.push(v);
            return res;
        }, []);
        return r;
    }

    /*
        Helper function
        @param string n
        @return bool
    */
    function isInt(n) {
        return n % 1 === 0;
    }


    /*
        Decides which filter function to call and stacks all filters together
        @param string filterType (the property that will be filtered upon)
        @param string value (selected filter value)
        @return undefined
    */
    function filterCtrl(filterType, value) {
        // result array
        var results = [];

        if( isInt(value) ) {
            filter[filterType] = parseInt(value);
        } else {
            filter[filterType] = value;
        }

        for( k in filter ) {
            if( !filter.hasOwnProperty(k) && !( filter[k] !== 0 ) ) {
                // all the filters are off
                loadMarkers();
                return false;
            } else if ( filter[k] !== 0 ) {
                // call filterMap function and append to r array
                results.push( filterMap[k]( filter[k] ) );
            } else {
                // fail silently
            }
        }

        if( filter[filterType] === 0 ) results.push( personData );

        /*
            if there is 1 array (1 filter applied) set it,
            else find markers that are common to every results array (pass every filter)
        */
        if( results.length === 1 ) {
            results = results[0];
        } else {
            results = reduceArray( results );
        }

        loadMarkers( results );

    }

    /* 
        The keys in this need to be mapped 1-to-1 with the keys in the filter variable.
    */
    filterMap = {
        applications: function( value ) {
            return filterIntsLessThan('applications', value);
        },

        town: function( value ) {
            return filterByString('town', value);
        },

        constituency: function( value ) {
            return filterByString('constituency', value);
        },

        stream: function( value ) {
            return filterByString('stream', value);
        },

        party: function( value ) {
            return filterByString('party', value);
        },

        startDate: function( value ) {
            return filterByString('startDate', value);
        }

    }

    /*
        Filters marker data based upon a string match
        @param string dataProperty (the key that will be filtered upon)
        @param string value (selected filter value)
        @return array (applicants that made it through the filter)
    */
    function filterByString( dataProperty, value ) {
        var applicants = [];

        for( var i=0; i < personData.length; i++ ) {
            var person = personData[i];
            if( person[dataProperty] == value ) {
                applicants.push( person );
            } else {
                removePersonMarker( person.id );
            }
        }
        return applicants;
    }

    /*
        Filters out integers that are under the provided value
        @param string dataProperty (the key that will be filtered upon)
        @param int value (selected filter value)
        @return array (applicants that made it through the filter)
    */
    function filterIntsLessThan( dataProperty, value ) {
            var applicants = [];

            for( var i=0; i < personData.length; i++ ) {
                var person = personData[i];
                if( person[dataProperty] > value ) {
                    applicants.push( person )
                } else {
                    removePersonMarker( person.id );
                }
            }
            return applicants;
    }

    // Takes all the filters off
    function resetFilter() {
        filter = {
            applications: 0,
            constituency: 0,
            town: 0,
            stream: 0,
            startDate: 0,
            party: 0
        }
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        loadMarkers: loadMarkers,
        filterCtrl: filterCtrl,
        resetFilter: resetFilter
    };
}();


$(function() {

    var mapConfig = {
        idSelector: 'map-canvas'
    }

    myMap.init( mapConfig );

    $('.load-btn').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // reset everything
        $('select').val(0);
        myMap.resetFilter();
        myMap.loadMarkers();

        if( $this.hasClass('is-success') ) {
            $this.removeClass('is-success').addClass('is-default');
        }
    });

    $('.applications-select').on('change', function() {
        myMap.filterCtrl('applications', this.value);
    });

    $('.town-select').on('change', function() {
        myMap.filterCtrl('town', this.value);
    });

    $('.constituency-select').on('change', function() {
        myMap.filterCtrl('constituency', this.value);
    });

    $('.stream-select').on('change', function() {
        myMap.filterCtrl('stream', this.value);
    });

    $('.party-select').on('change', function() {
        myMap.filterCtrl('party', this.value);
    });

    $('.startDate-select').on('change', function() {
        myMap.filterCtrl('startDate', this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**  try using:
after all marker are plotted on map. use markers array where you have `pushed all markers`.

```
new MarkerClusterer(map,markers);
```

see this sample code.it may help you:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 

       ShowHelperMap();
}); 
  function ShowHelperMap() {
        var ctr =new google.maps.LatLng(17.3660, 78.4760);
        var Locations=JSON.parse('[{"Lat":"17.5048667","Lng":"78.4143219"},{"Lat":"17.501313","Lng":"78.4286192"},{"Lat":"17.4865184","Lng":"78.449826"},{"Lat":"17.4963517","Lng":"78.4326133"},{"Lat":"17.4939323","Lng":"78.4420625"},{"Lat":"17.4654334","Lng":"78.4554779"},{"Lat":"17.465164","Lng":"78.45617"},{"Lat":"17.4667402","Lng":"78.4576088"},{"Lat":"17.5043837","Lng":"78.4155832"}]');
         var mapOptions = {
                    center: ctr,
                    zoom: parseInt(10),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false
                  };
         var myInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        var locationMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        var l;
        var markers=[];
            if (Locations && Locations.length > 0) {
                for (l = 0; l < Locations.length; l++) {
                    store = Locations[l];               
                    var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(store.Lat), parseFloat(store.Lng)),
                        map: locationMap
                    });

                    markers.push(centerMarker);
                }
            }
            new MarkerClusterer(locationMap,markers);

        }
```

```
<div id="map" style="width:98%;height:100%;margin:0 auto;" ></div>
```